# why aspnetcore service responsetime increase with increase in number of concurrent clients?

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, webapi

I have ASPNETCORE webapi.

controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase {
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }     

    [HttpGet("data")]
    public Stream GetData() {            
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TestData\1");
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        foreach (var file in files) {
            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);           
        return stream;
    }
}
```

program.cs:

```
 public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

startup class:

```
 public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Below requests are sent using jmeter with ramp up duration as 0, which means all requests are concurrent.

Below is the response time table req: http://localhost:5000/api/values/data (involves IO)

[image]

Below is the response time table req: http://localhost:5000/api/values (involves NO IO)

[image]

So my question is, why as the number parallel/concurrent requests increase the response time increasing?
though apsnetcore webapi uses worker threads to serve each request why cant they all complete in same time?

Could any one please explain why does independent worker threads taking more time when there more concurrent requests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you are reading the same files over and over again and from the disk reads constraint, your time will definitely go up as you increase the number of concurrent calls.

Comment: You are reading and writing to a stream in a blocking fashion. The reason why the response times are going up is due to thread starvation. Use the `async` versions of stream write and read.

Comment: @JohanP That's generally a good advice. Though here it's a memory stream where it doesn't really matter. The issue is at `File.ReadAllBytes`, which would need to be replaced by an async FileStream.

Comment: how about http://localhost:5000/api/values which has to just return just constant string value. even in this case the response time increasing, cant it use 100 worker threads to return all responses in shortest time.